# App Engine Datastore takes up to 1 hour to reach consistency

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, eventual-consistency

After updating a record in the datastore, a query to that record returns sometimes the correct data and sometimes stale data. It takes up to 1 hour for the data to replicate.

Is that regular behavior of the datastore eventual consistency? I'd expect that changes in the datastore take up to 2 minutes to propagate, but not an hour.

Comment: If you use a transaction it reads consistency data. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#Java_What_can_be_done_in_a_transaction. Or maybe you have an issue with cache configuration, because one hour is too long to be a consistancy issue.

Comment: Since the premise of your question isn't true, best to just delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. After all it wasn't the fault of the datastore, but rather the cache of objectify. Disabling it's cache fixed the issue.